# Merge multiple columns into one while repeating two columns

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

For example, I have a csv table:

```
Name, Val1, Val2, Val3, Constant      
a,    0.1,  0.6,  1.1,  0.21      
b,    0.2,  0.7,  1.2,  0.22      
c,    0.3,  0.8,  1.3,  0.23      
d,    0.4,  0.9,  1.4,  0.24      
e,    0.5,  1.0,  1.5,  0.25
```

I would like to combine columns 2,3 and 4 into a new column (let's say called Val5) while repeating the values in columns 1 and 5. This is how the output should look:

```
Name, Val5, Constant      
a,    0.1, 0.21   
b,    0.2, 0.22   
c,    0.3, 0.23   
d,    0.4, 0.24   
e,    0.5, 0.25       
a,    0.6, 0.21   
b,    0.7, 0.22   
c,    0.8, 0.23   
d,    0.9, 0.24   
e,    1.0, 0.25       
a,    1.1, 0.21   
b,    1.2, 0.22   
c,    1.3, 0.23   
d,    1.4, 0.24   
e,    1.5, 0.25
```

Answer (score 1):

To create val5:

```
df['val5'] = #Whatever you want it to be
```

To delete val1-3:

```
del df['val1']
del df['val2']
del df['val3']
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach is [`pandas.melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.melt.html) (I suppose a `Name` column is index in your data, so I reset it before melt):

```
melted_df = df.reset_index().melt(
    ['Constant', 'Name'], ['Val1', 'Val2', 'Val3'], value_name='val5'
)
melted_df

Out:
    Constant Name variable  val5
0       0.21    a     Val1    0.1
1       0.22    b     Val1    0.2
2       0.23    c     Val1    0.3
3       0.24    d     Val1    0.4
4       0.25    e     Val1    0.5
5       0.21    a     Val2    0.6
6       0.22    b     Val2    0.7
7       0.23    c     Val2    0.8
8       0.24    d     Val2    0.9
9       0.25    e     Val2    1.0
10      0.21    a     Val3    1.1
11      0.22    b     Val3    1.2
12      0.23    c     Val3    1.3
13      0.24    d     Val3    1.4
14      0.25    e     Val3    1.5
```

So just drop unnecessery columns (`variable`) and set correct index column:

```
df = melted_df.set_index('Name')[['val5', 'Constant']]
df 

Out: 
      val5  Constant
Name                
a      0.1      0.21
b      0.2      0.22
c      0.3      0.23
d      0.4      0.24
e      0.5      0.25
a      0.6      0.21
b      0.7      0.22
c      0.8      0.23
d      0.9      0.24
e      1.0      0.25
a      1.1      0.21
b      1.2      0.22
c      1.3      0.23
d      1.4      0.24
e      1.5      0.25
```

Hope it helps